# rich messages contains duplicate error messages, how to get unique messages

Tags: java, jsf

i am validating fields in rich datatable i.e when it is text i need to show error message as please follow policies, when a field fails, an error message is displayed in rich:messages tag, suppose if all the fields in rich table fails it shows "please follow policies" for all fields, i.e please follow policies prints for all fields, but i want to show the error only once

I tried immediate = true, it skips validation and also it skips updating modal

i tried globalOnly=true , then error message prints in logs but not on screen and stops further process.

Comment: Could we see a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: So an `h:messages` does **NOT** show duplicate messages

Comment: <rich:messages style="color:red; margin:8px;font-size:12px;" />
<rich:dataTable id="clients" value="#{client.priceToLevelMapping}" var="price" styleClass="content-tab-table" >
   <rich:column width="25%">
      <h:inputText value="#{price.price}" converterMessage=" Please follow  policies"/>
   </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>                                                                                                                         in the above example if we give text as input for all the rows it gives "please follow policies" for all rows, i want to print only once

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table and for each row, an input component is generated, you are going to get 1 validation error per invalid input: is the default behavior.

Consider: create your own custom validator for your requirement.

Comment: i tried to create custom validator, but in data in javax.faces.component.UIInput class it is converted to null so custom validator code will not get excuted for these fields.